# Close code review without opening?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I moved one of our top-level folders which has many files below.  Since it's policy to create a code review request for every commit, I did so.  Opening the review takes a loooong time as it tries to load every file in the hierarchy and eventually crashes Visual Studio.  Is there any way to close/abandon the review without opening it?

Comment: You can probably set the Status of the WorkItem via the TFS API to `Closed` - I don't have an environment to test at the moment until I am in work tomorrow.

Comment: @DaveShaw: I tried going down this route but had issues connecting to TFS, everything looked OK (URL, etc.) I and didn't want to spend too much time debugging.  However, this idea helped me find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remembered I had TFPT (Team Foundation Power Tools) installed, checked if there was anything related to work items and got lucky.  I looked up the work item ID from Visual Studio (for example, 1234) and did the following:

1. Run `tfpt workitem 1234`.  This gave me a dump of fields and their values.
2. Run the above command for another code review that was already closed.
3. Compare #1 and #2 to see what the differences were
4. Run the following command to close the original review: `tfpt workitem 1234 /update /fields:"State Code=1;Closed Status=Completed;Closed Status Code=3;Closed By=My User ID;Closed Date 1/1/2000 12:00 PM;Reason=Closed;State=Closed"`

I tried changing the `Changed Date` field but that wasn't allowed.  I was also missing one of the fields and was getting a `TFS237124: Work Item is not ready to save` error, but eventually got the right combination.